# Ionic2 How to update Ion menu items from a child component/modal

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm following [This example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#menus) and all is good but now I want to update the menu items that were initialized using:

```
this.pages = [
  { title: 'Getting Started', component: GettingStartedPage },
  { title: 'List', component: ListPage }
];
```

and

```
<ion-list>
  <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="#p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    {{p.title}}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

but now I'm inside a child component and I no longer have access to this.pages . How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between ionic pages use the `NavController`. If you want to pass data from parent to child, declare a `@Input()` Variable in the child component.

Here the angular2 docs about component communication: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

About using `NavController`: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavParams/

Answer (score 0):

Child components can then send Events up to the parent, to expand on what @muetzerich said.